# Why should a part of the updated posterior variance using kalman filter have a negative sign?

Tags: variance, kalman-filter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc6Kq.jpg)

Hi, I am learning the Kalman filter and am really confused at the estimated posterior variance. The conditional posterior variance has a negative term, but to me, it is supposed to have a positive sign. Could anyone explain why that (yellow colored part in the attached image) has a negative sign?

While deriving a variance, multiplying the same term with a negative sign naturally results in a positive sign.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Hi, pleaes refer to the attached file. I highlithed what I was curious about.